# Set default date for bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am trying to open the bootstrap datepicker on the date stored in the var `startDate`.

The code below is not working as the default date format for the datepicker is mm/dd/yy. `startDate` is in the format dd/mm/yy.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function toggle_dp() {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          defaultDate: new Date('{{ startDate }}')
        });
        $("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
    }
</script>
```

For example, if the `startDate` is 05/03/2018 (5th March), the datepicker will open with default date 03/05/2018 (3rd May).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formate: instead of dateFormat:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function toggle_dp() {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yy',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          defaultDate: new Date(toMMDDYYYY(startDate))
        });

    }

function toMMDDYYYY(date) {
            var datePart = date.split("/");
            var MMDDYYYY = [datePart[1], datePart[0],datePart[2]].join('/');
            return MMDDYYYY
        }
</script>
```

Comment: This produces the same result as my code. What i am trying to do is change the format of the datepicker to dd/mm/yy, but my code is not having any effect.

Comment: Try Using format: instead of dateFormat: updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have written the wrong syntax for `format`. Just replace `dateFormat` with **`format`** in your script code like below

> More help on [**Bootstrap Date-picker Format**](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggle_dp() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      defaultDate: new Date('{{ startDate }}')
    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "format", "dd-mm-yy");
  }
</script>
```